# Intellij IDEA 14 Remote Debug ignores breakpoints

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm working with a spring based project in java 1.6. I have a remote debug configuration to local tomcat server which worked without problems. Today I have encountered a problem with it. I place breakpoints in my code but they have not the valid symbol and are ignored while debugging, I have no idea why. I tried to clean/rebuild the project , invalidate cache but no effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How do you connect to tomcat procces?
From Intellij debug button, or do you start tomcat manualy, with debug keys in tomcat's proccess?
Are you 100% sure, that this line of code should execute? Maybe it makes sence to log anything on that line of code, so as too see that a problem is definatly in debug-connection?

Comment: I connect with Intellij button , the connection is fine . I debuged this part of code , changed some things , recompiled and restarted tomcat and I have no longer possibility to debug this part . I realized that breakpoints placed in classes which belongs to spring package works fine. The problem is with other classes from others packages